# Python Split and calculate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use an API for the license overview, there I can see when and for how long I have used a program.

The usage time is displayed in a table as 10 min or as 1 h 10 min.
Now I would like to have an printout under this table with the total used usage time.

```
for item in (data['data']):
    if item['un'] == tecNo:
        xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")
        print(xyz)
```

It Prints:

```
['20', 'min']
['35', 'min']
['1', 'h', '40', 'min']
['55', 'min']
['15', 'min']
['2', 'h']
['4', 'h', '25', 'min']
['15', 'min']
['30', 'min']
['45', 'min']
['1', 'h', '10', 'min']
['5', 'min']
['1', 'h', '10', 'min']
['35', 'min']
['55', 'min']
['1', 'h']
['1', 'h', '5', 'min']
['25', 'min']
['30', 'min']
['10', 'min']
```

How can I now calculate this so that I can print: `"You have used X hours and Y minutes in total"`?

Thank you very much!

**The working Code**

```
    total_hour = 0
    total_min = 0
    for item in (data['data']):
        if item['un'] == tecNo:
            xyz = item['tu'].split(" ")
            if xyz[1] == 'h':
                total_hour += int(xyz[0])
            if xyz[1] == 'min':
                total_min += int(xyz[0])
            if len(xyz) > 2:
                total_min += int(xyz[2])
    total_hour += (total_min // 60)
    total_min = (total_min % 60)
    print("You have used " +str(total_hour) + " h and " + str(total_min) + " m in total!")
```

Comment: I'd imagine splitting this actually makes it harder and there is probably a python library to do this for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total_hour = 0
total_min = 0
for item in (data['data']):
    if item['un'] == tecNo:
        xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")
        if xyz[1] == 'h':
            total_hour += xyz[0]
        if xyz[1] == 'min':
            total_min += xyz[0]
        if len(xyz)>2:
            total_min += xyz[2]
total_hour += (total_min//60)
total_min = (total_min%60)
print(total_hour+' h '+ total_min+ ' m')
```

Comment: if xyz[3]:
IndexError: list index out of range, thats the errormessage i get

Comment: @FabianBreuer -  I have corrected the code, please check

Comment: Had to make some changes, but it workes Thank you
        total_hour = 0
        total_min = 0
        for item in (data['data']):
            if item['un'] == tecNo:
                xyz = item['tu'].split(" ")
                if xyz[1] == 'h':
                    total_hour += int(xyz[0])
                if xyz[1] == 'min':
                    total_min += int(xyz[0])
                if len(xyz) > 2:
                    total_min += int(xyz[2])
        total_hour += (total_min // 60)
        total_min = (total_min % 60)
        print(str(total_hour) + "h" + str(total_min) + "m")

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple `for-loop` and `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
import math

data = [['10', 'min'], ['20', 'min'], ['35', 'min'], ['1', 'h', '40', 'min'], ['55', 'min'], ['15', 'min'], ['2', 'h'], ['4', 'h', '25', 'min']]
h, m = 0, 0
for d in data:
    for x, y in zip(d[0::2], d[1::2]):
        if y == "h":
            h += float(x)
        else:
            m += float(x)

if m > 60:
    m = m/60
    val = math.modf(m)
    h += val[1]
    m += val[0]

if h:
    print("You have used {} hours and {} minutes".format(h, m))
else:
    print("You have used {} minutes.".format(m))
```

**Output:**

```
You have used 10.0 hours and 3.66666666667 minutes
```

Comment: I meant that the data should be added together and then output below: "You have used X hours and Y minutes in total." sry

Comment: Oh ok. Updated snippet

Comment: Hey my result must be 18 hours and 45 min. But your Code gives me 18 hours and 8.5 min back :/

Comment: Can you post the data set which is giving  you  the error ?

Comment: [['20', 'min'], ['35', 'min'], ['1', 'h', '40', 'min'], ['55', 'min'], ['15', 'min'], ['2', 'h'], ['4', 'h', '25', 'min'], ['15', 'min'], ['30', 'min'], ['45', 'min'], ['1', 'h', '10', 'min'], ['5', 'min'], ['1', 'h', '10', 'min'], ['35', 'min'], ['55', 'min'], ['1', 'h'], ['1', 'h', '5', 'min'], ['25', 'min'], ['30', 'min'], ['10', 'min']]

Comment: it should be 19 hrs and 25 mins right for the above data set?

Comment: No, it should be 18 Hours and 45 min. The Solution and the Data set is in my question above. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
for item in (data['data']):
    if item['un'] == tecNo:
       xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")
       print("You have used {time} in total".format(time=" ".join(xyz))
```

**EDIT:**

```
for item in (data['data']):
    if item['un'] == tecNo:
       xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")
   if xyz[1] == "min"
       print("You have used 0 hours {min} minutes in total".format(min=xyz[0]))
   elif len(xyz) == 4:
       print("You have used {hour} hours {min} minutes in total".format(hour=xyz[0], min=xyz[2]))
   else:
       print("You have used {hour} hours 0 minutes in total".format(hour=xyz[0]))
```

Comment: Hey, I meant that the data should be added together and then output below: You have used X hours and Y minutes in total.

Comment: I see, I have made an edit. I hope you are looking for what I did.

Comment: print("You have used {hour} hours {min} minutes in total".formatjoin(hour=xyz[0], min=xyz[2]))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'formatjoin'

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo issue. I have fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to sum up the total time your code outputs, and instead, output a formatted string? You could try...

```
sum = 0

for item in (data['data']):
        if item['un'] == tecNo:
           xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")

           if len(xyz) == 4:
               sum += 60*xyz[0] + xyz[2]
           else:
               sum += xyz[0]
        hours = (sum//60)
        mins = sum - 60*hours
        print("You have used {X} hours and {Y} minutes".format(hours, mins))
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
data = [
['10', 'min'],
['20', 'min'],
['39', 'min'],
['1', 'h', '40', 'min'],
['55', 'min'],
['15', 'min'],
['2', 'h'],
['4', 'h', '25', 'min'],
]
sum = 0
for t in data:
    if t[1]== 'h' and len(t) > 2:
        sum += (int(t[0]) * 60) + int(t[2])
    elif t[1] == 'h':
        sum += (int(t[0]) * 60)
    elif t[1] == 'min':
        sum += int(t[0])

s = 'you have used {0:d} hours and {1} minutes.'.format((sum//60), (sum % 60))
print(s)
```

**output:**

```
you have used 10 hours and 24 minutes.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there's a mistake in your code. The hours are not given correctly. Another one has already solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
total_time = 0
for item in (data['data']):
    if item['un'] == tecNo:
        xyz= item['tu'].split(" ")
        if len(xyz)>2:
            total_time += 60*int(xyz[0]) + int(xyz[2])
        else:
            total_time += int(xyz[0])

if total_time>60:
    hours = total_time//60
    mints = total_time%60
    print("You have used {} hours and {} minutes".format(hours,mints))
else:
    print("You have used {} minutes".format(total_time))
```

output:

```
You have used 8 hours and 22 minutes
```